# Lucene - Out of Memory Error

Tags: java, indexing, lucene

I would like to store large amounts of file content (upwards of 75000 files with sizes around 5-100MB) in an index and run searches on it using Lucene 5. 
I'm using `FSDirectory` and I'm writing all file contents using an `IndexWriter`. As more files are written the memory usage increases until eventually an `Out of Memory` exception is thrown.

Here is an example of how I'm currently doing this.

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
FSDirectory directory = FSDirectory.open(indexFilePath);
DirectoryReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);   

IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);

IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, config);

for (Document document : documents)
{
    writer.addDocument(document);
}

writer.close();
```

I've been changing options around like these for the config but I've noticed no differences.

```
config.setMaxBufferedDocs(2);
config.setRAMBufferSizeMB(32);
config.setRAMPerThreadHardLimitMB(32);
```

I've also tried committing, flushing, and forcing merges with the writer but this doesn't affect it.

Is it possible to lower/limit the memory usage of Lucene?

Comment: during what operation you have oom? did you try periodical flush/commit things?

Comment: During the document adding loop in the example. I've tried putting flush/commit after these.
I have a feeling that the high memory usage is because of there are a lot of files being loaded in and it stores things in memory to use for searching.

Comment: could you try doing commits every 10-100 documents? not in the end?

Comment: I meant I've tried adding flush/commit inside the loop so it is called every time. I also have tried having a separate loop running flush/commit every few minutes.

Comment: do you actually need to store the large text in the index? if you are just going to search these documents and return the document ID or document title, you don't need to store the body of the document in the index

Comment: I need to search for any files that contain particular keywords. Wouldn't the content need to be in the index to search for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can Perform the lucene data indexing chunk by chunk.
If you are full data indexing, perform the first chunk data indexing in IndexWriterConfig CREATE mode.

```
 config.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE);
```

For indexing remaining chunks of data, set the IndexWriterConfig mode to CREATE_OR_APPEND

`config.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);`

This will perform incremental indexing, by appending the current data set to the existing lucene index.

Call these methods in each incremental indexing/chunk data indexing.

```
writer.optimize();
writer.commit();
writer.close();
```

TieredMergePolicy  configuration can also be set explicitly only in the case of incremental indexing,
for reflecting the delete, modidfication or addition of records to the index immediately on the search

```
TieredMergePolicy t  = new TieredMergePolicy();
t.setForceMergeDeletesPctAllowed(.01);
config.setMergePolicy(t);

writer.forceMergeDeletes();
writer.commit();
```

This is the way of doing indexing chunk by chunk. Since we are doing chunk by chunk. This will release the memory in each chunk.

Lucene indexing may or may not be the root cause of out of memory issue. Use `Memory Analyzer tool` to check which all java objects are not getting garbage collected in memory causing out of memory issue.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm trying this out now.
In Lucene 5 there doesn't seem to be an optimize method in the writer. Is there an alternative?

Comment: It seems like,there is no optimize() method above 4.0. versions. No need to use this. In the 3.6 docs, its mentioned like,

@Deprecated
public void optimize()throws CorruptIndexException,IOException
This method has been deprecated, as it is horribly inefficient and very rarely justified. Lucene's multi-segment search performance has improved over time, and the default TieredMergePolicy now targets segments with deletions. 

https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#optimize()